# Install YAJL in iPad project

Tags: iphone, json, ipad, yajl

Ireally need help. I want to use YAJL in my iPad project. I add YAJL framework to my project. But when I run my project I receive this error :

dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/gabe/Library/Frameworks/YAJL.framework/Versions/A/YAJL
  Referenced from: /Users/census/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/ED64B511-BD23-49F6-BAEF-8DD5E36F12D1/WebCensus1.0.app/WebCensus1.0
  Reason: image not found

Please help me. What can I do ?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Edit target build settings (see `Project > Edit Active Target`).

Look for `Runpath Search Paths` (under Linking) and put in `@loader_path/../Frameworks`

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried SBJSON ( http://stig.github.com/json-framework/ ) instead of YAJL. I have never had any problems with it.

Comment: Sir Can you just explain me how can i use SBJSON for Twitter Search API please??